# "unknown error code 132" with IBM Swift Sandbox

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array, error-handling, jagged-arrays, ibm-swift-sandbox

*(I'm pretty new to this, so tips on the general form of this post and my code are greatly appreciated!)*

---

I've been playing around with Swift in the [IBM Sandbox](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl), and I can't seem to get around the following problem:

```
func fillPossibilityMatrix() {        //it's a 9x9 Matrix
for i in 0...80 {
    let row = (i - (i % 9)) / 9       //-> row is Valid for 0 - 8
    let column = i % 9                            
    if possibilityMatrix[row, column] == [0] {
        possibilityMatrix[row, column] = possibilities(row, column: column)
    }
}
```

This gives me 132 unkown error!

- Even though I can call **possibilityMatrix** and **possibilities()** with every combination of values used here, as soon as I put "=" in between them, things get weird.
- I've seen the 132 error before, when I tried to assign Values to invalid indexes of Arrays/Matrixes, but I don't see that here...

-
The following *works perfectly fine*. (Note the "**print**s" instead of the "=")

`func fillPossibilityMatrix() {
        for i in 0...80 {
            let row = (i - (i % 9)) / 9
            let column = i % 9
            if possibilityMatrix[row, column] == [0] {
                print(possibilityMatrix[row, column])
                print(possibilities(row, column: column))
            }
        }
    }`

- It also works, when I put different Ranges for the Loop. But it's neither certain values being used nor the size of the Range, that determines whether it does or not.

Whats wrong here? Am I just being stupid? Is this specific to the IBM site?

---

### The Rest

*(I'm trying to let it solve Sudoku)*

-

**possibilityMatrix** comes about like this:
(here: field <-> possibilityMatrix)

```
struct Matrix {
    let rows: Int, columns: Int
    var grid: [[Int]]
    init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        grid = Array(count: rows * columns, repeatedValue: [0])
    }
   func indexIsValidForRow(row: Int, column: Int) -> Bool {
        return row >= 0 && row < rows && column >= 0 && column < columns
    }
    subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> [Int] {
        get {
            assert(indexIsValidForRow(row, column: column), "Index out of range")
            return grid[(row * columns) + column]
        }
        set {
            assert(indexIsValidForRow(row, column: column), "Index out of range")
            grid[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
        }
    }
}
var inputArray = [Int!] ()
var input = "003020600900305001001806400008102900700000008006708200002609500800203009005010300"
var field = Matrix(rows: 9, columns: 9)

for char in input.characters {
    inputArray.append(Int(String(char)))
}
func fromInputToField() {
    for i in 0..<inputArray.count {
        let row = (i - (i % 9))/9
        let column = i % 9
        field[row, column][0] = (inputArray[i])
    }
}
fromInputToField()

var possibilityMatrix = field
```

-

**possibilities()** and it's sub functions look like this:

```
func possibilities(row: Int, column: Int) -> [Int] {
    let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    return numbers.filter {
        !rowContains(row, number: $0) && !columnContains(column, number: $0) && !boxContains(row, c: column, number: $0)
    }
}


func rowContains(r: Int, number: Int) -> Bool {
    for i in 0...8 {
        if possibilityMatrix[r, i][0] == number {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func columnContains(c: Int, number: Int) -> Bool {
   for i in 0...8 {
        if possibilityMatrix[i, c][0] == number {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func boxContains (r: Int, c: Int, number: Int) -> Bool {
    let boxLocation = locateBox(r, c: c)
    for x in 0...2 {
        for y in 0...2 {
            if possibilityMatrix[boxLocation.0 + y, boxLocation.1 + x][0] == number {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

func locateBox (r: Int, c: Int) -> (upBorder: Int, leftBorder: Int) {
    if r % 3 != 0 {
        return locateBox(r - 1, c: c)
    }
    if c % 3 != 0 {
        return locateBox(r, c: c - 1)
    }
    return (r, c)
}
```

---

---

---

***for copy-pasting***

```
struct Matrix {
    let rows: Int, columns: Int
    var grid: [[Int]]
    init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        grid = Array(count: rows * columns, repeatedValue: [0])
    }
   func indexIsValidForRow(row: Int, column: Int) -> Bool {
        return row >= 0 && row < rows && column >= 0 && column < columns
    }
    subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> [Int] {
        get {
            assert(indexIsValidForRow(row, column: column), "Index out of range")
            return grid[(row * columns) + column]
        }
        set {
            assert(indexIsValidForRow(row, column: column), "Index out of range")
            grid[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
        }
    }
}
var inputArray = [Int!] ()
var input = "003020600900305001001806400008102900700000008006708200002609500800203009005010300"
var field = Matrix(rows: 9, columns: 9)

for char in input.characters {
    inputArray.append(Int(String(char)))
}
func fromInputToField() {
    for i in 0..<inputArray.count {
        let row = (i - (i % 9))/9
        let column = i % 9
        field[row, column][0] = (inputArray[i])
    }
}
fromInputToField()

var possibilityMatrix = field
func possibilities(row: Int, column: Int) -> [Int] {
    let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    return numbers.filter {
        !rowContains(row, number: $0) && !columnContains(column, number: $0) && !boxContains(row, c: column, number: $0)
    }
}


func rowContains(r: Int, number: Int) -> Bool {
    for i in 0...8 {
        if possibilityMatrix[r, i][0] == number {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func columnContains(c: Int, number: Int) -> Bool {
   for i in 0...8 {
        if possibilityMatrix[i, c][0] == number {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func boxContains (r: Int, c: Int, number: Int) -> Bool {
    let boxLocation = locateBox(r, c: c)
    for x in 0...2 {
        for y in 0...2 {
            if possibilityMatrix[boxLocation.0 + y, boxLocation.1 + x][0] == number {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

func locateBox (r: Int, c: Int) -> (upBorder: Int, leftBorder: Int) {
    if r % 3 != 0 {
        return locateBox(r - 1, c: c)
    }
    if c % 3 != 0 {
        return locateBox(r, c: c - 1)
    }
    return (r, c)
}
func fillPossibilityMatrix() {        //it's a 9x9 Matrix
    for i in 0...80 {
        let row = (i - (i % 9)) / 9       //-> row is Valid for 0 - 8
        let column = i % 9                            
        if possibilityMatrix[row, column] == [0] {
            possibilityMatrix[row, column] = possibilities(row, column: column)
        }
    }
}
fillPossibilityMatrix()
```

Comment: Can you show the declarations for `possibilityMatrix` and `possibilities`?

Comment: Your "for copy-pasting" code generates an error: "Array index out of range" (in a Playground and once compiled with open-source Swift). I think this is what 132 means.

Comment: @Eric D. But as I've just added in the post: if instead of assigning possibilities() to possibilityMatrix in the last function fillPossibilityMatrix(), you just print them it works perfectly fine. How do you make sense of that? Which Array?

Comment: We just took a look at error 132 on the backend, and that is indeed an `Index out of range` error you're getting. Our next update to the Sandbox should give a better error message.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense You're a developer of the sandbox? That's so cool!

Comment: Thanks! :D Anyhow I figured out the issue. I'm writing up an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the problem is a pretty simple one. Here are your possibility functions:

```
func rowContains(r: Int, number: Int) -> Bool {
    for i in 0...8 {
        if possibilityMatrix[r, i][0] == number {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func columnContains(c: Int, number: Int) -> Bool {
   for i in 0...8 {
        if possibilityMatrix[i, c][0] == number {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func boxContains (r: Int, c: Int, number: Int) -> Bool {
    let boxLocation = locateBox(r, c: c)
    for x in 0...2 {
        for y in 0...2 {
            if possibilityMatrix[boxLocation.0 + y, boxLocation.1 + x][0] == number {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

The problem is that you're checking `probabilityMatrix` to see if the number exists - which is the variable that you are modifying as you go. So if you change `probabilityMatrix[0, 0]` to equal `[4, 5]`, then when you check `probabilityMatrix[0, 1]`, your functions will assume that `4` is in that first row, because of the change you just made. Part of its check is looking at the first element of `probabilityMatrix[0, 0]`, which is `4`, so your code thinks that the first row naturally has a `4` in it.

After enough of this, you will eventually get to a square where the list of possibilities is `[]`, because the erroneous numbers accumulate as you go along a row (or column or box) and eventually all possibilities disappear. Then on the very next pass, a function like `rowContains` will look at that `[]` and try to get the first element from it (like in `possibilityMatrix[r, i][0]`), which doesn't exist. This is the cause of your `Index out of range` error.

The solution is to compare to `field` instead of `possibilityMatrix`, since that variable never changes and always holds the original matrix. So your functions should look like this:

```
func rowContains(r: Int, number: Int) -> Bool {
    for i in 0...8 {
        if field[r, i][0] == number {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func columnContains(c: Int, number: Int) -> Bool {
   for i in 0...8 {
        if field[i, c][0] == number {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func boxContains (r: Int, c: Int, number: Int) -> Bool {
    let boxLocation = locateBox(r, c: c)
    for x in 0...2 {
        for y in 0...2 {
            if field[boxLocation.0 + y, boxLocation.1 + x][0] == number {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Here's the working version implemented in the Sandbox for you to look at:

http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/6fe779409351531ce07d3bc3f0c197639538729b40d5f0f658e4dd53985223fe

EDIT: while learning recursion is a good thing, it's also good to avoid it if you can, since it takes up more resources than an iterative loop (since each time you call a function, it's placed on the program stack and takes up resources). Here's a faster way of achieving the same result:

```
func locateBox (r: Int, c: Int) -> (upBorder: Int, leftBorder: Int) {
    return ((r - (r % 3)), (c - (c % 3)))
}
```

Also, your `fillPossibilityMatrix()` function might work better as a double loop, since 1) the division and remainder functions are a little bit computationally expensive, and 2) it's easier to read.

```
func fillPossibilityMatrix() {        //it's a 9x9 Matrix
    for row in 0...8 {
        for column in 0...8 {                        
            if possibilityMatrix[row, column] == [0] {
                possibilityMatrix[row, column] = possibilities(row, column: column)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This did it. I got it running now - if anybody cares: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/26c7948d09498a283c1c5ec8d13c245aa235ff821213f5a0163df8a22fc79894